# Python 2.7 Export csv file with data

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to export my data into a csv file

My code is as follows

```
x1=1
x2=2
y1=1
y2=4
z1=1
z2=2 

a = (x1,y1,z1)
b = (x2,y2,z2)
def distance(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2):
 return (((x2-x1)**2)+((y2-y1)**2)+((z2-z1)**2))**0.5
w=distance(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2)
print w
if w>1 and w<2:
    time = 1
if w>2 and w<3:
    time = 2
if w>3 and w<4:
    time = 3

import csv

with open('concert_time.csv', 'w') as output:
```

I am stuck at this last line.  I would like a file with two columns for 'Letter Combinations' and 'Time', and the output to look like:

```
Letters         Time
a and b           3
```

I know there is a way to get this output by explicitly labeling a row as '3' for the appropriate time, but I would like a csv file that will change if I change the values of a or b, and thus the value of 'time' would change.  I have tried

```
writer.writerows(enumerate(range(time), 1))
```

but this does not get me the desired output (in fact it is probably very far off, but I am new to Python so my methods have been guess and check)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could first test your output by using print statements. try `print '%s and %s,%s' % ( 'a','b',time)` . When you have it ready, writing to a csv file is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

completing your code for `csv` writer. Also make sure to open file as `wb` on windows so that carriage return (newline) is added automatically.

```
with open('concert_time.csv', 'wb') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(["Letter Combinations", "Time"]) #header
    writer.writerow(["a and b", time]) #data
```

Content of `concert_time.csv`:

```
Letter Combinations,Time
a and b,3
```